# MySQL:how to join two separate columns and return it as result?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two MySQL queries,

query 1:

```
 select adj_close from market order by date desc limit 1,4;
```

output 1:

```
+-----------+
| adj_close |
+-----------+
|    106.15 |
|     111.4 |
|    111.45 |
|    115.45 |
+-----------+
```

and Query 2:

```
select open from online order by date desc limit 4;
```

output 2:

```
+--------+
| open   |
+--------+
|     98 |
|  109.9 |
|    111 |
| 117.45 |
+--------+
```

I want to join these two column together and want to return as result of select statement,
so i write query as below,

```
select T.adj_close, S.open from 
 (
 select adj_close from market order by date desc limit 1,4
 ) as T, 
(select open from online order by date desc limit 4
) as S;
```

and it gives me **unexpected output** as below,

```
+-----------+--------+
| adj_close | open   |
+-----------+--------+
|    106.15 |     98 |
|    106.15 |  109.9 |
|    106.15 |    111 |
|    106.15 | 117.45 |
|     111.4 |     98 |
|     111.4 |  109.9 |
|     111.4 |    111 |
|     111.4 | 117.45 |
|    111.45 |     98 |
|    111.45 |  109.9 |
|    111.45 |    111 |
|    111.45 | 117.45 |
|    115.45 |     98 |
|    115.45 |  109.9 |
|    115.45 |    111 |
|    115.45 | 117.45 |
+-----------+--------+
```

and i'm **expecting** my output as below,

```
    +-----------+--------+
    | adj_close |  open  |
    +-----------+--------+
    |    106.15 |    98  |
    |     111.4 |  109.9 |
    |    111.45 |   111  |
    |    115.45 |  117.45|
    +-----------+--------+
```

Please help me to solve this problem,

Comment: please the necessary table data that gets you your result, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What is your MySql version?

Comment: You've done a *nested select* - for each result in the first select, you get all of the results from the 2nd one.

Comment: if you have mysql 8 use row number in your select and join bith aat the same row number.

Comment: @belwood yes, what should i do to get expected output.

Comment: @forpas  8.0.20 MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t1.adj_close, t2.open
from (
  select adj_close, row_number() over (order by date desc) - 1 rn 
  from market 
  order by date desc 
  limit 1,4
) t1 inner join (
  select open, row_number() over (order by date desc) rn  
  from online 
  order by date desc limit 4
) t2 on t2.rn = t1.rn
```

Comment: both tables are different. even after changing the table name, it is not giving expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for this since both columns of data seem to be coming from the same table:

```
select `adj_close`, `open` from `market` order by `date` desc limit 1,4;
```

Comment: yeah it is coming from same table but i'm not using the corresponding data of 'adj_close' and 'open'.